# Controlling an external web page through javascript code (not same-origin)

Tags: javascript, python, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am trying to let an user control an external webpage using his mic. Now im at that point, that accessing elements from that webpage from my javascript code is not allowed due to cross-origin policy.
I understand the problem if i try to access that page, if its running in an iframe in my page. But is it possible to open a new tab and control that through mine ?

I have built the same functionality with python running on my pc, by using https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/. This program opens a browser window and then I can get every element from the webpage, click buttons and input text.
Why cant I do the same thing from my webpage? (I understand the cross-origin policy)

Are there any ideas how i can solve my problem or has somebody another idea how to solve that use case?

EDIT:
app.jsx (not working due to same-origin policy)

```
function InsertNumber(number){
var iframe = document.getElementById("dartcounter");
var elmnt = 
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("score");
console.log(elmnt)
//elmnt.innerHTML = "number";
}
export default function App() {
const [number, setNumber] = useState();

return (
    <div>
        <iframe id="dartcounter" src="https://dartcounter.net/en/game/match" width={1300} height={700}></iframe>
        <button onClick={() => InsertNumber(5)}>ID</button>
   </div >
)
```

main.py (running locally and working):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver =webdriver.Chrome('/Users/danielusselmann/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.dartcounter.net/de")
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[contains(.,"Rückgängig")]')
elem.click()
```

Comment: what does this have to do with python ?  where is the code ?

Comment: I don’t get the difference. If I do that with JavaScript via my web app it’s not possible. But if I do it with a local python program, it works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There doesn't exist any `cross-origin policy`. Only a [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), and it's enforced by web browsers and prevents JS code in one document to interact with documents loaded from another domain domain. I don't think there's anyway around it. It works in Python, because that code is not executed by your web browser, so the same-origin policy is not enforced.

Comment: I added my code. As i said its clear for me that the same origin policy applies here, but I dont get the difference, is it really just because im using an app in my browser?

Comment: @D.U.  it would work in NodeJS,  just not JS in the browser...  But in any event, it is helpful to pick a single language and work with that.

Comment: @D.L How would you do that ? So how would the architecture look like?

Comment: you can download node here:  https://nodejs.org , and run it in a similar way that you run the same python code. it is really convenient too.

Comment: @D.L so you would send it to the backend running and would access the webpage through that ? But then I wouldnt need my Webapp right ?

Comment: @D.U:   yes, that is correct.  You can use a backend language like NodeJS or python (there are others but these are the most popular) to achieve this.

Comment: @D.L can you write that down as answer and vote this post up? Then I can mark that as answer for others that will overcome this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have upvoted the post and written down the answer. The question is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

In summary to the discussion above.

It is possible to use any back end language (python and nodejs) are two popular options.

The code is written in a script and run from the server side (in the simplest case, this could be your laptop or pc).

This would eliminate the need for a Webapp altogether.

Since the code in the question is written in javascript, you can usr nodejs here: https://nodejs.org

You can find the same webdriver for selenium here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

And npm install like this (which is the equivalent to pythons pip install):

```
npm install selenium-webdriver
```